# Reshape rows into column, with two conditions (a ~ b, per c, per d)

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataframe like so:

```
item   price source   day
book   5     shop     2012-01-01
car    100   shop     2012-01-01
desk   10    shop     2012-01-01
book   4     internet 2012-01-01
car    99    internet 2012-01-01
desk   9     internet 2012-01-01
book   6     shop     2012-01-02
car    101   shop     2012-01-02
desk   11    shop     2012-01-02
book   4     internet 2012-01-02
car    100   internet 2012-01-02
desk   10    internet 2012-01-02
```

I would like, per day, each price per item, like:

```
item price.shop price.internet day
book 5          4              2012-01-01
car  100        99             2012-01-01
desk 10         9              2012-01-01
book 6          5              2012-01-02
car  101        100            2012-01-02
desk 11         10             2012-01-02
```

I have been trying my best with

`melt`'ing and then

```
cast(df, item ~ source + variable)
```

But can't get the desired result. I think the issue is becase i have in essence two "per thing" conditions (per `day`, per `source`) and so dont have the correct equation.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a plyr.reshape2 answer but using base:reshape():

```
> reshape(dat, idvar=c("item", "day"),  timevar="source", direction="wide")
  item        day price.shop price.internet
1 book 2012-01-01          5              4
2  car 2012-01-01        100             99
3 desk 2012-01-01         10              9
7 book 2012-01-02          6              4
8  car 2012-01-02        101            100
9 desk 2012-01-02         11             10
```

I suppose one could also could have tried a `merge(subset_shop, subset_internet, 1:2,  all=TRUE)` strategy.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this maybe:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "item   price source   day
book   5     shop     2012-01-01
car    100   shop     2012-01-01
desk   10    shop     2012-01-01
book   4     internet 2012-01-01
car    99    internet 2012-01-01
desk   9     internet 2012-01-01
book   6     shop     2012-01-02
car    101   shop     2012-01-02
desk   11    shop     2012-01-02
book   4     internet 2012-01-02
car    100   internet 2012-01-02
desk   10    internet 2012-01-02",header = TRUE,sep = "")

> library(reshape2)
> dcast(dat,item + day ~ source,fun.aggregate = sum,value.var = "price")

  item        day internet shop
1 book 2012-01-01        4    5
2 book 2012-01-02        4    6
3  car 2012-01-01       99  100
4  car 2012-01-02      100  101
5 desk 2012-01-01        9   10
6 desk 2012-01-02       10   11
```

Comment: Seems like dcast is a function from the package reshape2. Would be good to add library(reshape2) in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps unexpected approach (since Joran and DWin banged out the reshape alternatives in no time): `ftable` and `xtabs` working together. Assuming a `data.frame` called "dat":

```
ftable(xtabs(price ~ item + day + source, dat))
#                 source internet shop
# item day                            
# book 2012-01-01               4    5
#      2012-01-02               4    6
# car  2012-01-01              99  100
#      2012-01-02             100  101
# desk 2012-01-01               9   10
#      2012-01-02              10   11
```